# Spring integration - Task executor with SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

In my application , I am trying to make an Asynchronous call to a service so that I don't have to wait for that expensive call .  I am using SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor but no luck .  See below my code snippet.  Any idea what am I  missing .

My requirement :
Request comes to main channel ie issuTicket, it will check for a header value and can go to flow1_channel or flow2_channel. flow2 is an expensive call , so I want to start on a new thread.

I tried with a SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor , thought that it will make an Asynch call , but from the logs it looks like the main thread is still waiting for the flow2_channel to complete.  Any ideas?  Thanks in advance for loookign into this

```
 Config file :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration" xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
   xmlns:int-xml="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/xml" xmlns:int-ws="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ws"
   xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c" xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
   xmlns:int-http="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http" xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/spring-integration-3.0.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http/spring-integration-http-3.0.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/xml http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/xml/spring-integration-xml-3.0.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ws http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/ws/spring-integration-ws-3.0.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm.xsd
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/http/spring-integration-http-3.0.xsd
               http://www.springframework.org/schema/task http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd">

   <!-- Channel definition -->
   <int:channel id="flow2_channel">
      <int:dispatcher task-executor="asynchThread" />
   </int:channel>

   <int:channel id="flow1_channel" />

   <bean id="asynchThread" class="org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor">
      <property name="concurrencyLimit" value="20" />
   </bean>

   <!-- Main entry -->
   <int:chain input-channel="issueTicket">
      <int:filter expression="headers['status'] == 'TRUE'" discard-channel="flow1_channel" />
      <int:gateway request-channel="flow2_channel" />
   </int:chain>

   <int:chain input-channel="flow2_channel">
      <!-- time consuming call -->
      <int-http:outbound-gateway url="http://localhost:8080" http-method="POST" />
   </int:chain>

</beans>


  Unit test :
package com.swacorp.ais.createBooking.springorchestration;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.integration.MessageChannel;
import org.springframework.integration.support.MessageBuilder;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;

@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:createBooking/TestContext.xml"})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class SampleTest {

   @Autowired
   private MessageChannel issueTicket;

   @Before
   public void setUp() throws Exception {
   }

   @Test
   public void test() {
      issueTicket.send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("test").setHeader("status", "TRUE").build());
   }

}


---------------
From logs:
2015-09-04 13:29:51,029 DEBUG [main] {} [org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain]- org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain#0 received message: [Payload=test][Headers={timestamp=1441391391029, id=5f7c6af9-5efa-4cca-a274-2fa35097e10d, status=TRUE}]
2015-09-04 13:29:51,029 DEBUG [main] {} [org.springframework.integration.filter.MessageFilter]- org.springframework.integration.filter.MessageFilter@4c71eba0 received message: [Payload=test][Headers={timestamp=1441391391029, id=5f7c6af9-5efa-4cca-a274-2fa35097e10d, status=TRUE}]
2015-09-04 13:29:51,029 DEBUG [main] {} [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory]- Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'integrationEvaluationContext'
2015-09-04 13:29:51,029 DEBUG [main] {} [org.springframework.integration.filter.MessageFilter]- handler 'org.springframework.integration.filter.MessageFilter@4c71eba0' sending reply Message: [Payload=test][Headers={timestamp=1441391391029, id=5f7c6af9-5efa-4cca-a274-2fa35097e10d, status=TRUE}]
2015-09-04 13:29:51,029 DEBUG [main] {} [org.springframework.integration.gateway.RequestReplyMessageHandlerAdapter]- (inner bean)#1 received message: [Payload=test][Headers={timestamp=1441391391029, id=5f7c6af9-5efa-4cca-a274-2fa35097e10d, status=TRUE}]
2015-09-04 13:29:51,029 DEBUG [main] {} [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory]- Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'integrationEvaluationContext'
2015-09-04 13:29:51,029 DEBUG [main] {} [org.springframework.integration.channel.ExecutorChannel]- preSend on channel 'flow2_channel', message: [Payload=test][Headers={timestamp=1441391391029, id=b8ec3256-13f0-b86f-f57c-e021e0541dd4, errorChannel=org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@2aed913b, replyChannel=org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@2aed913b, status=TRUE}]
2015-09-04 13:29:51,044 DEBUG [main] {} [org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor$ConcurrencyThrottleAdapter]- Entering throttle at concurrency count 0
2015-09-04 13:29:51,044 DEBUG [main] {} [org.springframework.integration.channel.ExecutorChannel]- postSend (sent=true) on channel 'flow2_channel', message: [Payload=test][Headers={timestamp=1441391391029, id=b8ec3256-13f0-b86f-f57c-e021e0541dd4, errorChannel=org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@2aed913b, replyChannel=org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@2aed913b, status=TRUE}]
2015-09-04 13:29:51,044 DEBUG [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] {} [org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain]- org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain#1 received message: [Payload=test][Headers={timestamp=1441391391029, id=b8ec3256-13f0-b86f-f57c-e021e0541dd4, errorChannel=org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@2aed913b, replyChannel=org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@2aed913b, status=TRUE}]
2015-09-04 13:29:51,044 DEBUG [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] {} [org.springframework.integration.http.outbound.HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler]- org.springframework.integration.handler.MessageHandlerChain#1$child#0.handler received message: [Payload=test][Headers={timestamp=1441391391029, id=b8ec3256-13f0-b86f-f57c-e021e0541dd4, errorChannel=org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@2aed913b, replyChannel=org.springframework.integration.core.MessagingTemplate$TemporaryReplyChannel@2aed913b, status=TRUE}]
2015-09-04 13:29:51,044 DEBUG [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] {} [org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper]- outboundHeaderNames=[Accept, Accept-Charset, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, Accept-Ranges, Authorization, Cache-Control, Connection, Content-Length, Content-Type, Cookie, Date, Expect, From, Host, If-Match, If-Modified-Since, If-None-Match, If-Range, If-Unmodified-Since, Max-Forwards, Pragma, Proxy-Authorization, Range, Referer, TE, Upgrade, User-Agent, Via, Warning]
2015-09-04 13:29:51,044 DEBUG [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] {} [org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper]- headerName=[timestamp] WILL NOT be mapped
2015-09-04 13:29:51,044 DEBUG [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] {} [org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper]- headerName=[id] WILL NOT be mapped
2015-09-04 13:29:51,044 DEBUG [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] {} [org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper]- headerName=[errorChannel] WILL NOT be mapped
2015-09-04 13:29:51,044 DEBUG [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] {} [org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper]- headerName=[replyChannel] WILL NOT be mapped
2015-09-04 13:29:51,044 DEBUG [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] {} [org.springframework.integration.http.support.DefaultHttpHeaderMapper]- headerName=[status] WILL NOT be mapped
2015-09-04 13:29:51,060 DEBUG [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] {} [org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate]- Created POST request for "http://localhost:8080"
2015-09-04 13:29:51,060 DEBUG [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] {} [org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate]- Writing [test] as "text/plain;charset=UTF-8" using [org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter@688d9b8]
2015-09-04 13:29:52,076 DEBUG [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] {} [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory]- Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'errorChannel'
2015-09-04 13:29:52,076 DEBUG [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] {} [org.springframework.core.task.SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor$ConcurrencyThrottleAdapter]- Returning from throttle at concurrency count 0
2015-09-04 13:29:52,076 DEBUG [main] {} [org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener]- After test method: context [[TestContext@6f648f32 testClass = SampleTest, testInstance = com.swacorp.ais.createBooking.springorchestration.SampleTest@32f554c0, testMethod = test@SampleTest, testException = org.springframework.integration.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [(inner bean)#1], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@39cb7ee5 testClass = SampleTest, locations = '{classpath:createBooking/TestContext.xml}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]]], class dirties context [false], class mode [null], method dirties context [false].
2015-09-04 13:29:52,076 DEBUG [main] {} [org.springframework.test.context.web.ServletTestExecutionListener]- Resetting RequestContextHolder for test context [TestContext@6f648f32 testClass = SampleTest, testInstance = com.swacorp.ais.createBooking.springorchestration.SampleTest@32f554c0, testMethod = test@SampleTest, testException = org.springframework.integration.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [(inner bean)#1], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@39cb7ee5 testClass = SampleTest, locations = '{classpath:createBooking/TestContext.xml}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]].
2015-09-04 13:29:52,076 DEBUG [main] {} [org.springframework.test.context.support.DirtiesContextTestExecutionListener]- After test class: context [[TestContext@6f648f32 testClass = SampleTest, testInstance = [null], testMethod = [null], testException = [null], mergedContextConfiguration = [MergedContextConfiguration@39cb7ee5 testClass = SampleTest, locations = '{classpath:createBooking/TestContext.xml}', classes = '{}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{}', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.test.context.support.DelegatingSmartContextLoader', parent = [null]]]], dirtiesContext [false].
2015-09-04 13:29:52,076 INFO [Thread-0] {} [org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext]- Closing org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext@2b29f93b: startup date [Fri Sep 04 13:29:50 CDT 2015]; root of context hierarchy
2015-09-04 13:29:52,076 DEBUG [Thread-0] {} [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory]- Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.integration.config.IdGeneratorConfigurer#0'
```

Question :
Why the threads are not running parallel?
I can see main thread and then SimpleAsynchTaskExecutor and then main continues ...
What I  need is 
main , SimpleAsynchTaskExecutor  ,main, SimpleAsynchTaskExecutor etc ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is "upstream" of `flow2_channel`?

When asking questions like this, it's best to show all of your config.

If it's a gateway of some kind, you'll need to set `reply-timeout="0"` (or `default-reply-timeout` for a simple `<gateway/>`) if you want to ignore the reply.

**EDIT**

Since you are using a mid-flow gateway, if you don't want to wait for the result, you need to configure it so...

```
<int:gateway request-channel="flow2_channel" default-reply-timeout="0" />
```

This is what I said in my first answer.

That said, it's not clear why you have a gateway there at all; you can simply wire the two chains together with your async channel...

```
<int:chain input-channel="issueTicket" output-channel="flow2_channel">
    <int:filter expression="headers['status'] == 'TRUE'" discard-channel="flow1_channel" />
</int:chain>

<int:chain input-channel="flow2_channel" output-channel="nullChannel">
    <!-- time consuming call -->
    <int-http:outbound-gateway url="http://localhost:8080" http-method="POST" />
</int:chain>
```

Comment: There are only two chains , the issuTicket chan and flow2_channel.  I am sending a message to issuTicket chain from unit test.  I tried with reply-timeout but that didn't work.

Comment: You need to show your configuration. Where is the thread "hanging" - use jstack or a debugger. The reply-timeout=0 tells the thread to not wait.

Comment: The thread is not handing  but the flow is main thread()  .. then asynchThread and then main thread.. so  the flow is still synchronous.  I was expecting to see main ,asynchThread, main , asynchThread etc from logs

Comment: The flow is __not__ synchronous; the main thread hands off to the executor's thread. You said the main thread is stuck somewhere ... ` main thread is still waiting for the flow2_channel to complete` - exactly __where__ do you see it waiting?

Comment: Hi Gary, Appreciate your time .  I edited the question with full context and log details.  I want that two threads ( ie main and SimpleAsynTaskExecutor to run in parallel.  From the logs , it looks like the main thread is waiting for SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor to complete.

Comment: Thanks for showing the whole config this time - see the edit to my answer.

Comment: Thank You !  That really helped.

Comment: One more small edit - if you don't use a gateway, you need to set the `output-channel` to `nullChannel` to discard the result.